# Colorswatch filter shows Size as Color

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, color-swatches

I am working with Magento 1.9.1.0

I have 2 attributes as swatches (Color and Size).

**In layered Navigation:**

- select Blue--> shows blue swatch in filter
- select XL --> shows XL in Filter
- select blue and XL --> shows 2 times blue swatch in filter

Does anybody know that problem, and has maybe a solution?

Thank you!

[Demo with RWD Theme](http://demoshop-magentodedaily.magento-de-hosting.de/men/shirts.html?color=17&size=80)

[image: Examplescreenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Problem was inside:`app\code\core\Mage\ConfigurableSwatches\Block\Catalog\Layer\State\Swatch.php`

Method below:

```
protected function _init($filter)
{
    if (!$this->_initDone) {
        $dimHelper = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/swatchdimensions');
        $this->setSwatchInnerWidth(
            $dimHelper->getInnerWidth(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Swatchdimensions::AREA_LAYER));
        $this->setSwatchInnerHeight(
            $dimHelper->getInnerHeight(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Swatchdimensions::AREA_LAYER));
        $this->setSwatchOuterWidth(
            $dimHelper->getOuterWidth(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Swatchdimensions::AREA_LAYER));
        $this->setSwatchOuterHeight(
            $dimHelper->getOuterHeight(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Swatchdimensions::AREA_LAYER));

        $swatchUrl = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productimg')
            ->getGlobalSwatchUrl(
                $filter,
                $this->stripTags($filter->getLabel()),
                $this->getSwatchInnerWidth(),
                $this->getSwatchInnerHeight()
            );
        $this->setSwatchUrl($swatchUrl);

        $this->_initDone = true;
    }
}
```

It's check if protected flag `$_initDone` is false. For first time it is and path for swatch image creating. It's work fine for one Configurable Swatch.
But if we have two or more it's find path for first one and doesn't look for next, because flag `$_initDone` setup to true.

So my solution is Rewrite this block on your custom module. Copy paste this method, remove statement and variable `$this->_initDone = true;` showing below:

```
57: if (!$this->_initDone) {
77:        $this->_initDone = true;
78:    }
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrii is right. The problem is from:

> app\code\core\Mage\ConfigurableSwatches\Block\Catalog\Layer\State\Swatch.php

From the method where he said:

```
protected function _init($filter){
if (!$this->_initDone) {
    $dimHelper = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/swatchdimensions');
    $this->setSwatchInnerWidth(
        $dimHelper->getInnerWidth(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Swatchdimensions::AREA_LAYER));
    $this->setSwatchInnerHeight(
        $dimHelper->getInnerHeight(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Swatchdimensions::AREA_LAYER));
    $this->setSwatchOuterWidth(
        $dimHelper->getOuterWidth(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Swatchdimensions::AREA_LAYER));
    $this->setSwatchOuterHeight(
        $dimHelper->getOuterHeight(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Swatchdimensions::AREA_LAYER));

    $swatchUrl = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productimg')
        ->getGlobalSwatchUrl(
            $filter,
            $this->stripTags($filter->getLabel()),
            $this->getSwatchInnerWidth(),
            $this->getSwatchInnerHeight()
        );
    $this->setSwatchUrl($swatchUrl);

    $this->_initDone = true;
}
}
```

But my solution is to rewrite this method on your theme and change this line

```
$this->_initDone = true;
```

with this line

```
$this->_initDone = false;
```

This works for me and I hope it helps you too.